# What network vendor would you prefer if you want to manage LTE interfaces via API. Cisco Juniper ?? or other vendors

Tags: api, router, lte

I'm looking for a LTE router with API option , to manage interfaces via scripts , is there any recommendation ?

Comment: Maybe I'm biased, but Cisco has whole exam DEVNET intended for automation of their devices using different API's using python and such. There is a number of different API's you can use to manage their products. You can checkout their official docs https://developer.cisco.com/docs/. From personal experience, configuring Cisco devices using a bit of python is very neat. So from me, Cisco.

Answer (score 0):

Both are equally good. They come with wide range of APIs  for various configurations,  services provided by them.

The network router selection depends on your deployment requirements, use case scenarios in your hand.